# Json full of "\"

Tags: java, android

I'm putting a json inside another like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

for(.....){
  JSONObject v = new JSONObject();

  v.put("key", "value");
  v.put("key", "value");
  v.put("key", "value");

  json.put(i, v.toString());

  i++;  
}
```

The problem is that it is getting like this:

```
{"0":"{\"key\":\"value\",\"key\":\"value\",...}"}
```

Filled with "\", does anyone know how to withdraw or do the "right mode"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cause you put string in  json. change this:

from:

```
json.put(i, v.toString());
```

to:

```
json.put(i, v);
```